# What's the purpose of `val` property with `final` modifier?

Tags: kotlin, immutability

Recently IntelliJ suggested to add `final` to one of a `val` properties. This particular property was initialized in `init {}` block. I've tried to find out what is the semantics of `final val` construct and when should I use it, but Kotlin is all about immutability and how `val` is equivalent of `final` in Java and so results were so noisy, that I couldn't find anything.

Example:

```
final val id: Int // `final` suggested by IDE

init { id = 1 }
```

What is the meaning and possible usages of similar property? By applying `final` what limitations it implies beyond immutability, which is already known? Does it have anything to do with inheritance or external access?

IntelliJ stopped sugessting `final` if property is `private`.

Comment: Watch out when thinking a `val` is equivalent to Java `final`. A `val` can be implemented with a custom getter and return anything it wants. `class X { var mutable = 1; val immutableOrSoItSeems get() = mutable }`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The example as it is should not suggest adding `final` as it does nothing in this case. The only place where adding `final` makes sense in Kotlin is when [overriding members](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods). By adding `final` to an overridden property (or method), you're preventing subclasses from further overriding it.

For example:

```
open class A {
    open val x: Int = 0
}

open class B : A() {
    final override val x: Int = 25
}

class C : B() {
    override val x: Int = 56 // Error: `x` in `B` is final and cannot be overridden
}
```

The `final` keyword isn't really applicable if:

- the class you're in isn't `open`,
- the property isn't `open`,
- the property is `private`.

Comment: I've been confused because it's Springboot app with Gradle's Kotlin-Spring plugin. What it makes is, it opens bean classes for you implicitly. So the class looks closed, but is really opened. Now it makes much more sense. Thank you. :)