# Non-static @RegisterExtension field in Kotlin 1.4 with JUnit5

Tags: kotlin, junit, junit5

When using Java and JUnit 5 I can register an extension using a *non-static* field like this:

```java
@RegisterExtension
MyExtension myExtension = new MyExtension(...);
```

When I try to use Kotlin (1.4.10) instead, I cannot seem to get this to work. I've tried for example:

```kotlin
@RegisterExtension
val myExtension = MyExtension(...)
```

but it fails with:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Failed to register extension via @RegisterExtension field [private final com.something.SomeTest.myExtension]: field must not be private.
```

when I try to run it.

If I try to add an `@JvmField` annotation:

```kotlin
@JvmField
@RegisterExtension
val myExtension = MyExtension(...)
```

it fails with a compile-time error instead:

```
JvmField can only be applied to final property
```

What I *can* do is to move it to a companion object:

```kotlin
companion object {
    @JvmField
    @RegisterExtension
    val myExtension = MyExtension(...)
}
```

now it works. But I cannot declare `myExtension` inside a companion object because the input to the constructor (`...`) is not available yet. I simply want it to be executed the same way as it would in the Java example presented above.

How can I do this in Kotlin (1.4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue. I just had to make the field `final` in kotlin (in addition to annotatiing it with `@JvmField`):

```
val wiremockPort = 8081

@RegisterExtension
@JvmField
final val wireMockServer = WireMockTestRunner(wiremockPort)
```

Comment: `@JvmField` was sufficient for me. `val` in Kotlin already implies `final`, so `final` is redundant.

Comment: @Raman it used to be requirement in Junit so that the field cannot be overriden. Maybe it was changed - I don't have project at hand to check if it still required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982487/12092179 for details on what is the difference betwieen `final val` field and `val` field in `open` classess in kotlin.

Comment: As stated by that SO you linked `final` would only be relevant if the class and property were `open`. They are not. I can't speak to what older versions of JUnit were or were not doing. Could have just been a bug of some type, either in the Kotlin compiler or in JUnit.

Comment: The class was open in my case (and I guess in OP's case). It is not stated explicitly in question but the error message from question "JvmField can only be applied to final property" only happens in this case.The `open` can also be implicit when using `kotlin-allopen` plugin.